# Screenshot of particular columns&rows of a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

Imagine that I have a grid with 3 columns and 2 rows. I want to take a picture of what is inside the column 2-3 and row 1. Is this possible?

Right now I am able to take a screenshot to my plot graph with this method

```
private void Capture()
            {
                SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
                dlg.FileName = "hello";
                dlg.Filter = "JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG (*.png)";
                dlg.FilterIndex = 1;
                if (dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
                {
                    string filePath = dlg.FileName;
                    plotter.SaveScreenshot(filePath);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }

            }
```

Where plotter is a ChartPlotter (a class in DynamicDataDisplay), it has a method called "SaveScreenshot".

But it only takes the screenshot of that particular plotter. My idea is to have several plotters and be able to make a screenshot to all of them. For that I can put them into a StackPanel or a grid and take a picture of that element as whole (that contains all my plotters).

Answer (score 1):

yes it is. I don't know in what case exactly you would like to use it. but if you just want to save it in a nother array for example you could do this with for loops. for your example only one loop is needed:

```
int[,] array = new int[2,3];


static int[,] ScreenShot(int row, int colum1, int colum2)
{
    int[,] temp = new int[colum2-colum1, 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < colum2-colum1; i++)
    {
        temp[i,1] = array[i+colum1,row];
    }
}
```

if you want it to have more rows, you could extend it.

Comment: Thanks but how do I use that array to save a picture?

Comment: That would be a little more complex. can you describe a little more of the situation you want to use it in so i can give a better answer?

Comment: I've updated my question explaining it a little more. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This woudn't be the fastest or nicest solution, but you could make an array of plotters, then create a temporary array of small pictures (would use something more lossless then jpg) and combine them at the end. Would this work for you?

Comment: But there isn't something like capture everything on the screen in a specific area? (for example in a rectangle, a StackPanel, a grid...). There is another problem and that is I have a nice gradient background in my application and the plotters are set to have transparent background. If I capture them the way I described above the resultan background is black. So I think my only option is to find out how to screenshot something in a particular place. Thanks for the answers =)

Comment: if you draw everything, there is. Iknow XNA has a good way to take screenshots with either a Texture2D class or a RenderTarget2D class. its possible with both to do so. If not you could also write some hlsl  code to render a part of the screen and save that one as an image.

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate that XNA thing. 4:40 am here, time to go to bed. I'll post the solution if I find it.